# How to execute function using JQuery Confirm Dialog?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have something proble with my code.. I still didn;t understand how to execute function using Jquery Confirm Dialog.....
here's my code

```
       <table  align="left" id="tableQuestions" width="600">
         <tr id="rowQuestion">
          <td class="tblCell">Questions<br>
           <input type="text" name="question" size="50" id="question">
           <br>Answer<br>
            A. <input type="text" name="answerA" size="25" id="answerA"><br>
            B. <input type="text" name="answerB" size="25" id="answerB"><br>
            C. <input type="text" name="answerC" size="25" id="answerC"><br>
            D. <input type="text" name="answerD" size="25" id="answerD">
          </td>
          <td class="tblCell"><a href="#"><button class="up">Up</button></a>
           <a href="#"><button class="down">Down</button></a>
           <a href="#"><button class="removeStdInsBtn">Remove</button></a>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="rowQuestion">
          <td class="tblCell">Questions<br>
           <input type="text" name="question" size="50" id="question">
           <br>Answer<br>
            A. <input type="text" name="answerA" size="25" id="answerA"><br>
            B. <input type="text" name="answerB" size="25" id="answerB"><br>
            C. <input type="text" name="answerC" size="25" id="answerC"><br>
            D. <input type="text" name="answerD" size="25" id="answerD">
          </td>
          <td class="tblCell">
            <a href="#"><button class="up">Up</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button class="down">Down</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button class="removeStdInsBtn">Remove</button></a>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
        <table align="left" width="100" class="form">
         <tr>
          <td class="tblCell" width="50">
           <div class="btnInput"><a href="#"><input type="button" name="add" id="acctBtnAdd" value="ADD" class="btn"></a></div>
          </td>
          <td class="tblCell" width="50">
           <div class="btnInput"><a href="#"><input type="button" name="save" id="acctBtnSave" value="SAVE" class="btn"></a></div>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete Account?">
   <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These Account will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
  </div>
```

and here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

$('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: false,
   height:160,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
    DELETE': function() {
       **/*How can i delete rows here ???????*/**
    },
    'CANCEL': function() {
       $(this).dialog('close');
    }
     }
    });

}

 $('#tableQuestions tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
   /* I put my code here for delete row.. but must not here because it only call  $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');*/
   //$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();

});
```

Now, i put my code inside  $('#tableQuestions tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click to remove row.. but if i am using dialog confirm, inside of this function still call $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open'); so inside $('#dialog-confirm').dialog we will put our code to remove row.. but i can't and it doesnt work.... anybody could?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - Basically, each time the removeStdInsBtn is clicked it sets the 'buttons' on the dialog and passes along the element you want to remove if DELETE is clicked.

The current element is stored in a variable and passed along (if you tried to 'pass' *this* it would end up using the dialog button, not the row you wanted to delete.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){ 
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       resizable: false,
       height:160,
       modal: true,
    });

    $('#tableQuestions tr button.removeStdInsBtn').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var delItem = this;
       $('#dialog-confirm').dialog("option", "buttons", { "DELETE": function() { $(delItem).parent().parent().parent().remove(); },  "CANCEL": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }} );
       $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
    });
}
```